# Where can you see the console.log() output of a scratch2.0 extension?

Tags: raspberry-pi, console.log, mit-scratch

I am busy creating an extension for scratch2 on my raspberry pi (version scratch-flash = ba2f624-dirty).  I am loading this extension using the "Import experimental extension" menu.

In my extension javascript file I am using the console.log() command (like other extension developers do) but I have no clue where I can find this console.log() output.

So where can I find the console.log() output ?
Or alternatively is there a different log command that I can use in the raspberry pi scratch2 (offline editor) that is somewhere visible ?

E.g. an extract of my extension with a console.log() command.

```
window.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(message.data);

                //
                var event=msg['event'];
                incomingMessages[event]=true;
              lastEventValue[event]=msg['value'];
    console.log(message.data)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but console.log() logs to the browser console. Maybe try opening developer tools (ctrl + shift + I) by right clicking and clicking inspect, then click on console and check there.
I hope this helped.